# How can we record a one to one stream while one of the member is connected for 10 min then disconnected for 5 min then joined back again

Tags: javascript, react-native, opentok

1. Firstly I created a successful opentok session.
2. Now, both of the users getting each other stream.
3. Here I want to record the session, both user video-audio. ( Due to some functionality requirement).
4. To playback the whole stream later, I want the stream in the single recorded file.
5. But during the communication, one of the users get disconnected due to the bad internet connection and joined back the stream after 5 mins.
6. So, what will happen to that recorded file meanwhile the user got disconnected for 5 min in mid of the active session and joined back again?

---

I expect to have some blank screen until the user gets active again to the previous ongoing stream session in the recorded file.

Comment: According to the [OpenTok documentation](https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#stopping_an_archive_recording) that should not be an issue unless the second user also disconnects: "Archives stop recording ... 60 seconds after the last client disconnects from the session, or 60 minutes after the last client stops publishing." Is this a purely hypothetical question or did you actually implement and test something and ran into issues? If you did, please post your code and where the problem occurred.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, it's working perfectly as I expected. Now, looking for broadcasting use cases.